# How to create UUID from bytes when bytes comes from input() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, uuid

I'm using Python3 to get some useful UUID from string like this: \227L\310\210\r\232MG\2110\221?h$0\313

When I trying to make it manually by placing string to code, all works fine:

```
>>> from uuid import UUID
>>> print(UUID(bytes=b"\227L\310\210\r\232MG\2110\221?h$0\313"))
974cc888-0d9a-4d47-8930-913f682430cb
>>>
```

But if I take this string from input() function, Python adds some characters there (backslashes), so I can't use such string as UUID bytes argument:

```
from uuid import UUID
from codecs import encode


def give_client_id():
    input_str = input('Paste bynary string: ')
    print(input_str)
    
    bytes_str = bytes(input_str, 'ascii')
    print(bytes_str)
    
    encoded_str = input_str.encode()
    print(encoded_str)

    print(UUID(bytes=bytes_str))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    give_client_id()
```

This code always returns the same for me:

```
Paste bynary string: \227L\310\210\r\232MG\2110\221?h$0\313
\227L\310\210\r\232MG\2110\221?h$0\313
b'\\227L\\310\\210\\r\\232MG\\2110\\221?h$0\\313'
b'\\227L\\310\\210\\r\\232MG\\2110\\221?h$0\\313'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "give_client_id_from_bytes.py", line 19, in <module>
    give_client_id()
  File "give_client_id_from_bytes.py", line 15, in give_client_id
    print(UUID(bytes=bytes_str))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/uuid.py", line 178, in __init__
    raise ValueError('bytes is not a 16-char string')
ValueError: bytes is not a 16-char string
```

How can I force Python accept such string in UUID or re-format this string to something more useful?

Comment: FYI your code isn't utilizing the imported `encode` imported from `codecs`. Not that that's your issue though. Also, your string is being interpreted as being literal, the slash-escaped codes aren't getting decoded by your code, from what I can tell.

Comment: Thanks, Random Davis, yes, this escape code didn’t user, but when I tried it, I got the same string with backslashes.